# JS não está sendo carregado numa rota em RAILS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá! Tenho o seguinte trecho de código da home page do meu projeto:

```
      <li class="next" style="display: inline-block; margin: auto">
        <a href="/produtos">&rarr;</a>
      </li>
```

este hiperlink consegue chamar a página na rota /produtos, que possui este código:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Produtos</h1>

<table class="table table-hover custom" id="tabelaProduto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preco</th>
      <th>Descricao</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= produto.id %></td>
        <td><%= produto.nome %></td>
        <td><%= produto.preco %></td>
        <td data-jtable><%= produto.descricao %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', produto %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_produto_path(produto) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', produto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="botaosomar" value="OK"/>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Produto', new_produto_path %>
```

e na pasta javascripts, o arquivo JS desta view:

```
var valores_selecionados = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabelaProduto tr").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        var value=$(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html();
        var valor = parseFloat(value);
        valores_selecionados.push(valor);
        console.log(valores_selecionados);
    });
    $("#botaosomar").click(function(){
        var total=0;
        for(var i in valores_selecionados){
            total += valores_selecionados[i];
        }
        alert(total);
        valores_selecionados = [];

    })


});
```

Quando eu digito a rota /produtos diretamente na barra de endereços, consigo acessa-la e interagir com os elementos HTML com o JS que construí. Porém, quando clico no hiperlink da pagina inicial que me redireciona para esta, o JS não funciona como se nem existisse.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o motivo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600093/rails-javascript-not-loading-after-clicking-through-link-to-helper

(preciso pesquisar mais antes de postar a duvida :\ )